# Publishing in KDP direct from outside the US

Tags: self-publishing, kindle

I am currently based in Vancouver, BC and will soon be self-publishing with KDP. Although I'm now in Canada, my instinct is to publish on KDP USA rather than KDP Canada, because the USA KDP has a bigger selection of books, seem less strict when it comes to rating erotica as Adult (based on all my research) and have a much bigger market.

Is this just unnecessary because the book will be published in all Kindle markets anyway?

Is it best to just publish on your own country's platform?

Is there an advantage to publishing on KDP USA even if you are outside the US?

Thank you.

Comment: If differences between countries aren't made explicit in Amazon's documentation, I'm afraid you're unlikely to get a clear-cut answer - Amazon is notoriously tight-lipped and opaque about these kinds of details, and wide research is difficult. Hope you find out, or find a solution that works for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've published 6 books so far on KDP, and I'm based out of Calgary. When I log into kdp.amazon.ca, it actually redirects me to kdp.amazon.com. It's one and the same site.

I think what you're looking for firstly, is what marketplaces your KDP account is configured for. After you log into KDP, click on upper right-hand link for your account, mine says "Adam's Account."

This will bring you to a screen that has your address, and if you scroll down, you will a spot called Tax Information (make sure you've got a green checkmark there, if not, you have some work to do). After that is Amazon Marketplaces, that's where you'll see how you are going to get paid for each of the different marketplaces.

For my account, every marketplace states either EFT or cheque.

When I go to publish a title (and I just setup #7 today for pre-order), I just setup the information, upload the content, and set the price in all the various marketplaces. That's all I need to do. Amazon will publish my books from there.

People who want to buy your book will be required to go to the location associated with their account. For example, when I'm in Amazon.com looking at an eBook, I can't buy it. There's a link over on the right hand side which will take me to the equivalent page on the Amazon.ca site, which will then allow me to buy the book.

So there's no "publishing it on KDP US vs not," there is only publishing it. Everything else seems to be driven from how your account is configured.

I hope this helped,

Adam

Comment: Thanks so much Adam. I was away for a couple of weeks, so sorry for the late reply. I believe that being based in Canada, I will create an Amazon.ca account, but the book will be published in all the markets I chose and there is no disadvantage to me in terms of reaching the US market (the one I most want to reach). Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether the question refers to e-books or paperbacks. The problem for Canadians using the .com KDP application for a paperback version of their e-book is that it gets printed in the USA. Canadian purchasers have to pay shipping costs and import duty. A Canadian KDP application for paperbacks has just been announced (December 7 2016) so presumably that will solve the purchase problem for Canadian purchasers. US purchasers still able to buy in the US.

Answer (score -1):

I think, we just have to publish books in our Kindle Account. It will be showing in all local kindle domains. I just published books in my account, and traffic is coming from many countries. Royalties vary.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't matter which you go through? Can you explain which KDP country you publish through? Do you know anything about the specific questions OP is asking , or is it simply that you haven't noticed any ill effect?